# Is POS tagging deterministic?

Tags: python, nlp, machine-learning, nltk

I have been trying to wrap my head around why this is happening but am hoping someone can shed some light on this. I am trying to tag the following text:

```
ae0.475      X  mod 
ae0.842      X  mod
ae0.842      X  mod 
ae0.775      X  mod
```

using the following code:

```
import nltk

file = open("test", "r")

for line in file:
        words = line.strip().split(' ')
        words = [word.strip() for word in words if word != '']
        tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        pos = [tags[x][1] for x in range(len(tags))]
        key = ' '.join(pos)
        print words, " : ", key
```

and am getting the following result:

```
['ae0.475', 'X', 'mod']  :  NN NNP NN
['ae0.842', 'X', 'mod']  :  -NONE- NNP NN
['ae0.842', 'X', 'mod']  :  -NONE- NNP NN
['ae0.775', 'X', 'mod']  :  NN NNP NN
```

And I don't get it. Does anyone know what is the reason for this inconsistency? I am not very particular about the accuracy about the pos tagging because I am attempting to extract some templates but it seems to be using different tags at different instances for a word that looks "almost" the same.

As a solution, I replaced all numbers with 1 and solved the problem:

```
['ae1.111', 'X', 'mod']  :  NN NNP NN
['ae1.111', 'X', 'mod']  :  NN NNP NN
['ae1.111', 'X', 'mod']  :  NN NNP NN
['ae1.111', 'X', 'mod']  :  NN NNP NN
```

but am curious why it tagged the instance with different tags in my first case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My best effort to understand uncovered [this](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tag.html) from someone not using the whole Brown corpus:

> Note that words that the tagger has
>   not seen before, such as decried,
>   receive a tag of None.

So, I guess something that looks like `ae1.111` must appear in the corpus file, but nothing like `ae0.842`. That's kind of weird, but that's the reasoning for giving the `-NONE-` tag.

Edit: I got super-curious, [downloaded the Brown corpus](http://www.archive.org/details/BrownCorpus) myself, and plain-text-searched inside it. The number `111` appears in it 34 times, and the number `842` only appears 4 times. `842` only appears either in the middle of dollar amounts or as the last 3 digits of a year, and `111` appears many times on its own as a page number. `775` also appears once as a page number.

So, I'm going to make a conjecture, that because of [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), you will end up matching numbers that start with 1s, 2s, and 3s much more often than numbers that start with 8s or 9s, since these are more often the page numbers of a random page that would be cited in a book. I'd be really interested in finding out if that's true (but not interested enough to do it myself, of course!).

Comment: +1 for the Benford's law. And by the way you are right. They are indeed page numbers. In my experiment, any number > 790 is being given the None tag and for other it is giving the `NN` tag. :) Awesome catch!

Answer (score 3):

It is "deterministic" in the sense that the same sentence is going to be tagged the same way using the same algorithm every time, but since your words aren't in nltk's data (in fact, aren't even real words in real sentences) it's going to use some algorithm to try to infer what the tags would be. That is going to mean that you can have different taggings when the words change (even if the change is a different number like you have) and that the taggings aren't going to make much sense anyway.

Which makes me wonder why you're trying to use NLP for non-natural language constructs.

Comment: I love this response. It /is/ very questionable as to why NLTK is being used here. However, if it really is required, then a possible hack would be to define a custom corpus with all possible "words" and a custom chunker. But this seems like way too much work for something that should (and could) probably be done a lot simpler

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation. I am trying out a few exploratory techniques to figure out the best way to transform my data into some intermediate format that will aid in template extraction. This seems to work pretty well for my case (maybe not for every case).

Comment: Strictly speaking, NLTK's `pos_tag` is not required to be deterministic at all. Some machine learning algorithms flip coins internally.